# How to access NSMutableArray from Objective-C in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift

I created an `array` called events in Objective-C, and I want to be able to add events to the array in Swift. Here is my declaration of the property in Objective-C:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *events;
```

Here is my usage of the array in the Swift file.

```
var objectC = DPCalendarTestStoryboardViewController()

@IBAction func addMedicine(sender: AnyObject) {
    objectC.events = [].mutableCopy
    var event: DPCalendarEvent = DPCalendarEvent(title: nameText.text, startTime: startDatePicker.date, endTime: startDatePicker.date, colorIndex: 2)
    objectC.events.append(event)
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
Value of type 'DPCalendarTestStoryboardViewController' has no member 'events'
```

Comment: Have you created an objective c bridging header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C NSMutableArray and Swift Array are different. You can still use NSMutableArray and all its methods in Swift.

Replace Code with

```
@IBAction func addMedicine(sender: AnyObject) {
    objectC.events = NSMutableArray()
    var event: DPCalendarEvent = DPCalendarEvent(title: nameText.text, startTime: startDatePicker.date, endTime: startDatePicker.date, colorIndex: 2)
    objectC.events.addObject(event)
}
```

and also you need to declare events property in .h file and

instantiate your DPCalendarTestStoryboardViewController viewController using storyboard reference

```
var objectC =  UIStoryboard(name: "storyboardNameHere", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewControllerIdentifier") as? DPCalendarTestStoryboardViewController
```

Comment: It still has an error :( I think the problem has something to do more with how I'm calling the array from objectC. But thanks anyways!

Comment: You need to declare events property in .h file

Comment: Ugh, I got an error. Any idea how to fix it?                                         Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Technovation_2016.CategoryLabelTableViewController 0x7c072510> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key exerciseCell.'

Comment: yep, instantiate your DPCalendarTestStoryboardViewController viewController using storyboard reference

Comment: Um, sorry, how exactly do you do that?

Comment: Sorry, where do I put that?

Comment: Where you are initializing your objectC variable, updated my code.

Comment: Would that be instead of var objectC = DPCalendarTestStoryboardViewController()?

Comment: I added: var objectC =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main.storyboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CalendarID") as? DPCalendarTestStoryboardViewController. But it just went to the debugger (lldb). This happened when clicking a button to go to the next view controller.

Comment: Storyboard name will be only "Main", So code will be  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CalendarID") as? DPCalendarTestStoryboardViewController.      and also please make sure that you actually have included the identifier in storyboard for DPCalendarTestStoryboardViewController

Comment: What is CategoryLabelTableViewController ? Crash is causing because of this

Comment: It is just a table view controller that has 4 cells with labels for different categories of events.

Comment: Your IBOutlet connection to exerciseCell is broken, means you have removed the reference from your code, but it is still there in your storyboard

Comment: Please check the usage of exerciseCell in your CategoryLabelTableViewController.

Comment: I never made an IBOutlet connection... the cell is only connected to the Table View

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work. Thank you so much for all your help! Hopefully, there won't be anymore errors.